# How can I use helm with org-refile?

Tags: org-mode, helm

I'd like use `org-refile` and select the heading with helm with an interface like `helm-org-in-buffer-headings`.

I know I can use `helm-org-in-buffer-headings` to do this using `f2`, but is there a way to have `org-refile` do specifically this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer provided by Magnap didn't work for me, and neither did the accepted answer of this apparent duplicate: [Use Helm for Org Refile Completion](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51057/use-helm-for-org-refile-completion?rq=1)

What finally worked was this answer: [How to get helm completion for an arbitrary function such as dired or magit-branch?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/50298/how-to-get-helm-completion-for-an-arbitrary-function-such-as-dired-or-magit-bran?rq=1)

Just adding: `(helm-mode)` (I had previously been using helm only for specific things)

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to set `org-outline-path-complete-in-steps` to `nil`. This makes `org-refile` generate all possible paths when choosing where to refile to, rather than only the top level.

Comment: Also `(setq org-completion-use-ido nil)`