# How to get helm completion for an arbitrary function such as dired or magit-branch?

Tags: helm

I would like to use helm completion for something that is not directly supported via function like `helm-M-x` or `helm-mini`. An example would be `magit-branch`, which would really benefit from helm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable `helm-mode`:

```el
(helm-mode)
```

if you don't enable the mode, another choice is to customize the `magit-completing-read-function` option:

```el
(setq magit-completing-read-function 'helm--completing-read-default)
```

See also [`(info "(magit) Support for Completion Frameworks")`](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Support-for-Completion-Frameworks.html).

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! But the `1` or `t` to enable the minor mode is missing :P

`(helm-mode 1)`

Comment: @luckysori That's on purpose. Unlike many people use `(flyspell-mode 1)` and `(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)` at the same time, I like consistency so I always call `foo-mode` **without argument** to enable the minor mode. You can see many `(foo-mode 1)` are used to enable a minor mode because the code was wrote before 2012 (Emacs 24.1 introduced the new behavior, see https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/d0e2a341dd9a9a365fd311748df024ecb25b70ec/etc/NEWS.24#L3303)

Comment: That's really interesting! I swear not many people use that...