# Use Helm for Org Refile Completion

Tags: org-mode, helm

I want to use helm for org-refile completion when determining which heading to refile under.

Here are some excerpts from my initialization script.

```
(setq org-refile-targets '(("~/Documents/GTD/Gtd.org" :maxlevel . 3)
                           ("~/Documents/GTD/Someday.org" :level . 1)
                           ("~/Documents/GTD/Tickler.org" :maxlevel . 2)))


(setq org-outline-path-complete-in-steps nil)
(setq org-completion-use-ido nil)
```

I'm not sure what more I need to use helm in this manner. Do I need to rebind the refile key to a different command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are my settings. I got a lot of help on this from [Aaron Bieber's discussion](https://blog.aaronbieber.com/2017/03/19/organizing-notes-with-refile.html).

```
(setq org-refile-targets '((org-agenda-files :maxlevel . 8)
                           ("~/.emacs.d/config.org" :maxlevel . 8)))
(setq org-refile-use-outline-path 'file)
(setq org-outline-path-complete-in-steps nil)
(setq org-refile-allow-creating-parent-nodes 'confirm)
```

Helm works perfectly with these settings. I didn't have to set `org-completion-use-ido` to `nil`. I actually don't see that as a variable option at all (I'm using org 9.2.4).

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me with those settings. I am running on Windows so not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Actually, this does work I just had an error in my config. Thank you!